# FSL mobile app screen elements visibility based on a criteria

Tags: visual-workflow, field-service-lightning

We are implementing Field service Lightning. We have a requirement in our FSL mobile flow that on screen elements (text variables) should only be displayed if certain fields are checked which is similar to rendered in vfpages.

For ex: We have eleven product checkbox fields (each on screen variable representing each field), we want to display elements only if the product fields are checked. If four of the eleven fields are checked, we want to display only four of variables on screen. If it is only one or two fields instead of eleven, we would've used decision element but since it is 11 fields, that is not a possible option. I can use aura components but components are not supported on the FSL app yet. Any suggestions?